# Iphone Developer Program

Tags: iphone

Is there a restriction or limit for the number of installed/distributed iPhone applications with the Standard Program? (Individual and/or Company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be pedantic, there's no limit to the number of APPLICATIONS you can distribute, only the number of DEVICES that you may distribute to. As mentioned, you can distribute to 100 different DEVICES using the regular Developer license, but each device can have unlimited applications deployed to it.

Also, the 100 Device limit is reset each year.

Answer (score 2):

the basic $99 developer program allows for 100 ad hoc ( non app store ) deployments. the $299 program is for internal ad hoc applications for companys with 500 or more employees, all this is easily available on the developer.apple.com website.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no restriction if they are deployed through the appstore, distribution for an internal app using ad-hoc distribution is valid for up to 100 devices

Comment: If they're not (Ad Hoc/In-house distribution), there's still no limit.

Comment: Where did you get 50 devices from? It's 100, not 50.

Comment: Found it in another stackoverflow post, I'll change it :)